# How to render AWT components in SwingNode

Tags: java, swing, awt, javafx-8

Since javafx MediaView does not accept rtp streaming (am I wrong?) I'm trying to use LibJitsi.
My idea is to capture incoming stream and render it in a SwingNode. The problem is that [VideoMediaStream#getVisualComponent()](http://bluejimp.com/jitsi/libjitsi/javadoc/org/jitsi/service/neomedia/VideoMediaStream.html) from LibJitsi returns an AWT component and it seems that JavaFX SwingNode does not render AWT components, even if I wrap them in a JComponent.

Comment: You are not wrong, JavaFX 2 MediaView does not accept RTP. [Supported protocols are documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) and do not include RTP.

Comment: You might want to consider using [vlcj](https://code.google.com/p/vlcj/) instead of LibJitsi. vlcj streams RTP according to it's doc and, from [this forum](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2436712), can be [used by JavaFX](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-javafx/blob/master/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/javafx/test/JavaFXDirectRenderingTest.java).  If you go the vlcj integrated approach, render your video using a [PixelWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelWriter.html) interfacing to a JavaFX WritableImage rather than a JavaFX Canvas.

Comment: @jewelsea: I can't use vlcj. It is distribuited under the GPL license.